# jQuery.ajax beforeSend callback is not returning the right result

Tags: jquery

I understand that jQuery.ajax provides "beforeSend" callback. If this callback returns false then entire request is cancelled.

I verified that here http://jsfiddle.net/neerajdotname/9dBRY/10/ .

However take a look at slightly modified version http://jsfiddle.net/neerajdotname/sLnY8/6/

In this case beforeSend callback is triggering a previously registered event. The returned value of that trigger is used to determine if request should be cancelled or not.

As you can see I am returning false from triggered call. However that returned value is not equal to false.

Comment: I could be confused... but what exactly are you trying to achieve using beforeSend? Are  you trying to prevent the form from submitting? If that's the case you can use preventDefault() I'll explain in an answer if that's the case. If not, please elaborate - I see a few things wrong with your code but I'd need to know just what you are trying to do to help.

Comment: I an running into an issue with refactoring of code at https://github.com/neerajdotname/jquery-ujs . I think I should be allowed to trigger an event on $(this) in beforeSend.

Comment: explicitly returning from an event handler doesn't return the value to the calling code. If you return `non-false`, it does nothing, if you return `false` it prevents the default behavior of that event.

Comment: @Alex. I agree. return false from beforeSend only if you want to cancel the request. Otherwise return nothing.